# MSBUILDEMITSOLUTION not working with .NET 4?

Tags: msbuild, .net-4.0

In prior versions of MSBuild, you could set an environment variable named MSBUILDEMITSOLUTION to 1 to get an XML version of a solution (.sln) file that could be parsed. According to the [MSBuild Team Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/msbuild/archive/2010/07/09/debugging-msbuild-script-with-visual-studio-3.aspx), that's still in the version that ships with Visual Studio 2010, but it does not seem to be working.

Has anyone managed to get this working with MSBuild 4.0? If so, what is required?

(We use this to find and run convention-based unit tests with an NAnt script.)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Set `MSBuildEmitSolution=1` and then build from the command line. You should then see a MySolution.sln.metaproj file near MySolution.sln.

Notes:

- If you open a command prompt window, then set the env var via System Settings, you will have to open a new command prompt.
- You'd think you could also use `msbuild /p:MSBuildEmitSolution=1`, but you can't.

Comment: Thanks - now it's working. Wish I knew why it wasn't last night. ;)