# Building a solution file using msbuild

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild

I was about to build a Visual Studio solution file using msbuild. I used the following commandline for building the solution

```
msbuild.exe SolutionFile.sln /t:Build/p:Configuration=Release;Platform=Win32
```

Even though the build starts at some point the build is looking hang and fails to move forward as shown below

```
Done Building Project "D:\SolutionPath\ProjectFile10.vcxproj" (default targets).
```

There are a lot of `.proj` under `SolutionFile.sln` those I have to build.

I have to use `msbuild.exe` rather than `devenv.com`

Comment: please provide more information/msbuild output, this is impossible to answer now

Comment: you need a space between parameters.. `msbuild.exe SolutionFile.sln /t:Build /p:Configuration=Release;Platform=Win32`

Answer (score 35, accepted):

There's a technique for diagnosing what's happening inside msbuild which may help you work out what's happening here. From a command prompt set an environment variable:

```
set msbuildemitsolution=1
```

Once you have run msbuild then this will generate a `.metaproj` file. This file is what msbuild uses internally but then deletes. You can read it to find out the name of the actual targets are. The `Build` target is expanded to show what it actually calls.  You can then try building the individual targets with the `/t` flag of msbuild to work out which target is causing the problem.

Comment: Adding a link to the following since it explains how to get this output to show up. You have to set this property from different command lines. Great suggestion.   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3887263/msbuildemitsolution-not-working-with-net-4

Answer (score 30):

Set the verbosity property to diagnostic and save the output to a file. This will help you determine which project in your solution is hanging and help diagnose your problem.

The command line syntax would be as follows to save the output to a file named MyProjectOutput.log :

```
msbuild SolutionFile.sln /t:build /fl /flp:logfile=MyProjectOutput.log;verbosity=diagnostic
```

It also appears that you need a space after the /t target to build parameter passed in the command you listed.

```
msbuild.exe SolutionFile.sln /t:Build /p:Configuration=Release;Platform=Win32
```

Also, are you sure that every project contains a "Release" and "Win32" configuration?
You could try just running the below command as well and see what gets compiled. Msbuild will automatically run the default target and configurations needed.

```
msbuild SolutionFile.sln
```

Another option you can try is to just compile the project and see what is produced:

```
msbuild "D:\SolutionPath\ProjectFile10.vcxproj" /fl /flp:logfile=MyProjectOutput.log;verbosity=diagnostic
```

Comment: Does this work the same with .NET Core projects in a solution?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/cli-msbuild-architecture MSBuild has been ported to .net core and can run on any platform .net core runs on.

Comment: In other words, yes MSBuild is used to build the .Net core platform. It is the build engine, so yes.

Comment: Instead of your second command, I used `msbuild.exe SolutionFile.sln /t:Build /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform=Win32`. I think you need `/p:` short for `/property:` for each argument, and cannot use an argument list separated by semicolons.

Comment: @JohnDoe it’s a shortcut built into msbuild. You can specify /p: once and separate properties with ; . Both ways work however. Msbuild is pretty diverse