# MSbuild run specific targets for specific projects

Tags: msbuild

I am using following code in 2 our of 3 projects from the solution default target is set to *PublishMe*

```
<Target Name="PublishMe" DependsOnTargets="PipelinePreDeployCopyAllFilesToOneFolder">
    <Error Condition="'$(PublishDestination)'==''" Text="The PublishDestination property must be set to the intended publishing destination." />
    <MakeDir Condition="!Exists($(PublishDestination))" Directories="$(PublishDestination)" />
    <ItemGroup>
      <PublishFiles Include="$(_PackageTempDir)\**\*.*" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(PublishFiles)" DestinationFiles="@(PublishFiles->'$(PublishDestination)\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)')" SkipUnchangedFiles="True" />
</Target>
```

If I run msbuild it builds and publishes just as expected, the problem is that I can't build it from VS anymore, I am having error of missing *projectname.dll*

Is there way I can change default build target if it is msbuild doing build?

I tried to /t:ProjectName:target;ProjectName2:target, but it isn't working with custom targets for some reason.

Is there way I can specify param from msbuild console to run PublishMe target and if not present run simple build?

Comment: Additional note, I need to build from solution, not a single csproj

Comment: IIRC if you rename PublishMe to Build, it will override the actual Build target so it will be used automatically?

Answer (score 1):

You can usefollowing command

```
 msbuild projectname /t:targetname.
```

Also please check the below link for more info

[Building a solution file using msbuild](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14119498/building-a-solution-file-using-msbuild)

Comment: I need .sln not csproj, or there is elegant way to read whats in .sln?