# TFS build definition to build projects with multiple configurations, not common in all

Tags: tfs

I need to build 300+ projects on TFS. Some of the projects have mulitiple configurations i.e. some have 3 Release configurations, some have 5 Debug configurations. If I create one Build Definition for all projects, then those projects which doesn't have a specific configurations, would give unexpected results or may get failed.

**Update:**
**Q1**: What to do if building multiple projects with a configuration not defined in any one or some of these?
**Q2**: If I have to add more functionality in Build Definition XAML, is there any good tutorial/guide available for doing such customization?

Comment: This is a duplicate of the question you posed last week! (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24819397/tfs-building-solutions-with-multiple-configurations)
I already answered to it so, this should be closed as duplicate.

Comment: @GiulioVian: I think, its Title become same, but here I'm trying to get a solution of another scenario that What to do if building multiple projects with a configuration not defined in any or some of these. So I'll update it

Comment: However, your answer there seems covering this one as well, but I still have to explore that option :)