# Build on TFS one project in solution under different platforms

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012, tfs, tfsbuild

I have solution containing several projects. On of this projects I need build in Release configuration under x64 and AnyCPU platforms, other projects only for AnyCPU. In Visual Studio I can go to batch build window, check x64 and AnyCPU for my project, press build button and I will get bin --> {debug, release, x64} folder structure after it.

What better way do the same in TFS 2012?

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24819397/tfs-building-solutions-with-multiple-configurations/24822229#24822229

Comment: Yes, this was helpful, but another problem appeared - msbuild can't resolve references for my x64 project. Not all references, but only those located in AnyCPU projects. And I have no idea what happens.

Comment: you'll have to expand on that i can't really pick out the important bits.

Comment: try "Any CPU" rather than AnyCPU ?

Comment: No no, I'm tried Any CPU just written it in short form. I've already tried Any CPU + x64; Mixed Platforms + x64 but got the same bad result.

Comment: in your definition, under 5. Advanced is your MSBuild Platform set to X86? can you change it to Auto. or edit your question and add the error messages

Comment: No, MSBuild platform already set to Auto. Error messages - compiler can't find all types, storing in another projects. Once again, I have A, B, C projects, and in my build I need compile project A under Any CPU and x64 platforms, B, C only under Any CPU.