# Obtain visual studio generated build command

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

I want to create a batch file for building releases of a multi-solution software. What I am curious about how may I obtain the exact MSBuild command that Visual Studio executes when I click on "Rebuild Solution"?

Comment: There are *thousands* of such commands.  Just run MSBuild.exe in your batch file to get the same outcome.

Comment: This is why I want to obtain the EXACT command that VS generates when building MY solution. Is there a way to make VS log the MSBuild command it executes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is equivalent to

`MsBuild /t:Rebuild /p:Configuration=<config>;Platform=<platform>`

although VS actually generates a [temporary msbuild file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3887263/msbuildemitsolution-not-working-with-net-4) from the solution and then builds that. You get the file by setting an MSBuildEmitSolution environment variable:

- open a VS command window
- enter `set MSBuildEmitSolution=1`
- enter `devenv` to open a VS instance within that command window so it uses the MSBuildEmitSolution environment variable
- open and build your solution

Comment: Is there a way to obtain this temporary MSBuild file? The exact commands should be in there...

Comment: yes, that's in the link, I'll edit the answer to make this clear. But as I said, it should be equivalent to just calling MsBuild on the solution with the Rebuild target. Doesn't that work for you?