# MSBuild - Can I build for a Build Configuration without a solution?

Tags: msbuild

I want to build a project with a particular named Build Configuration, let's call it Conf-A.

This is running as an MSBuild step on TeamCity. When the build runs, it spits out:

> The OutputPath property is not set for project ... You may be seeing this message because you are trying to build a project without a solution file, and have specified a non-default Configuration or Platform that doesn't exist for this project.

This project is part of a hulking great solution we load on our dev machines.

The error makes sense for my situation, since I'm building just the proj file, but I don't want to use the solution file since I'm trying break-up this monolithic app.

I want the build-server to treat this project as it's own component, even if for the moment it is part of a solution and has references to other projects (assemblies) in the solution.

Must I build this via a solution file?

I could potentially copy the solution file and prune off all the other projects that are not required, but that's more complexity.

(Maybe the error is a red-herring).

Comment: BTW—Actually, building a solution is not natural for MsBuild. It first converts it to a project. If you want, you can see the [solution project](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3888083/2226988).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you dont need to build a sln. Its like the error says. You just havent specified a value for the variable OutputPath in your msbuild. You can add it to your files or you can pass it in at the cmd line - `msbuild someproj.proj /p:OutputPath=C:\notallovermydrive`